# Forward all traffic to index.php and obtain POST and GET request?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I'm currently developing a CMS based engine in PHP. First, I have all the page request forward to index.php, that will go through a bootstrap cycle and process the request. Then, I made a module that produces a form. However, when I go to submit the form, using method POST, the data is not received. I'm not sure if its due to the routing. Or some other form of dark magic.

This is currently my .htaccess

```
Options -Indexes
Options +FollowSymLinks
ErrorDocument 404 /index.php
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html index.htm

<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteBase /
  RewriteRule "(^|/)\." - [F]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/favicon.ico
  RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Comment: Is the request method still `POST` when you check it?

Comment: @zerkms I'm not 100% sure what you are asking. Is the form still using the method POST, yes.

Comment: A RewriteRule doesn't change the request type unless you are doing a redirect. PHP will still see and get post and get values.

Comment: @zerkms The REDIRECT_REQUEST_METHOD POST. However, REQUEST_METHOD GET.

Comment: And what zerkms is talking about is `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']`. That would have whatever method the page was requested. If the page was requested using POST as a form typically does, that would say `POST`.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn I think I understand what you mean. So, is there any specific place these vars are passed; without me having to rewrite my redirect statements?

Comment: Those rules posted aren't doing a redirect. They are doing a rewrite. The difference is that in a rewrite, you see one url and the server loads a different script. For example you load and see `/foo/bar/` and `/index.php` is loaded behind the scenes transparently. With a redirect, you go to one url and the server actually sends back a header saying "go to this different page". So you load `/foo/bar` and the server says `go to /index.php` and your url changes to `/index.php` and loads that page.

Comment: @JonathanKuhn Ok, I'm doing a rewrite. However, the POST and GET variables are not being passed to the index.php script.

Comment: Perhaps add `QSA` to the flags. So `[L]` should be `[L,QSA]`. That should help the get variables. The post variables shouldn't be affected if `$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']` is `POST`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63730/discussion-between-nateageek-and-jonathan-kuhn).